# VBA macro to replace all instance of regex X with string Y in Outlook 2010

Tags: vba, microsoft-outlook-2010

I want to invoke some macro which results in the currently active email draft being loaded to a variable and then replace each instance of a given regex with some string.

I'm particularly stuck on the first line below.  I can't find any simple tutorials that start near this step (all seem to start far early or far later).

PseudoCode:

```
myMessage = active message
someRegex = \d\d[:,]\d\d
someString = "(Time Entry)"
myMessage.HTMLBody = Replace(myMessage.HTMLBody, someRegex, someCharacter)
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the current message opened, use the following code:

```
Set myMessage = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
```